# Firestore task with for each loop

Tags: android, android-asynctask, google-cloud-firestore

I'm trying to retrieve document references from Firestore in a for loop (without iterating through the subset). I need to wait for the loop to finish, wait for data to be received and on success, submit this data to the Firestore. Currently, my method does not wait for data to be received what so ever since it is async.

It would probably be a good idea to create a method that returns a Task and then wait for a result. Suggestions?

```
ArrayList<String> documentPath = new ArrayList<>();
     private void getDocumentRef() {
        try {
            for (String path : documentPath) {
                db.document(path).get().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<DocumentSnapshot>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<DocumentSnapshot> task) {

                        if (task.isSuccessful() && task.getResult() != null) {
                            if (task.getResult().exists()) {
                                references.add(task.getResult().getReference());                      
                            }
                        }
                    }
                });
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {

        } 
    }
```

Comment: Are the documents you're looking for in the same collection?

Comment: Yes, they're from the same collection.

Comment: Why doesn't returning a Task work? That's exactly what you want to do.

Comment: @DougStevenson I need to add some context: I'm using a FirestoreRecyclerview to pass documents' path to a Fragment (because DocumentReference isn't serializable)  and I then need to retrieve DocumentReference for each path and parse it to an ArrayList to write to Firestore. I implemented the method as seen above, but when writing to the Firestore, the array didn't have any documents because they weren't retrieved before writing to the database. And since for loops and tasks don't go well together, I'm not sure what's the best way to solve this

Comment: And I'm relatively new to asynchronous programming, so I'm not sure how to properly make a method that will do exactly that.

Comment: Have you solved the issue?

Comment: @AlexMamo Haven't tested it yet. Another option would be parsing data through a ViewModel class since I have a recyclerview and can get references directly from it, so querying would be unnecessary.

Comment: @AlexMamo Well as it turns out I haven't done much in regards to the problem. Transaction does basically the same thing. Any idea how to solve this?

Answer (score 2):

If I understood your issue correctly, following method should work:

```
private void getDocumentRef(List<String> documentPaths) {
    List<Task<DocumentSnapshot>> tasks = new ArrayList<>();

    for (String path : documentPaths) {
        tasks.add(db.document(path).get());
    }

    Task<List<DocumentSnapshot>> finalTask = Tasks.whenAllSuccess(tasks);
    finalTask.addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<List<DocumentSnapshot>>() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(List<DocumentSnapshot> documentSnapshots) {
            /* This list contains all the retrieved document snapshots. Now iterate  
             through this list to get the document references.*/
            for (DocumentSnapshot snapshot : documentSnapshots) {
                references.add(snapshot.getReference());
            }
            /* Here u can do whatever u want with the list named references 
            because now it has references of all required documents. */
        }
    });
}
```

Here, we iterate through the supplied list of paths, create a separate `Task` for retrieving the document at that path and add this task to a list of `Task<DocumentSnapshot>`. Then, we supply this list to `Tasks.whenAllSuccess()` and create a new `Task` named `finalTask`. We then attach an `OnSuccessListener` to `finalTask` whose `onSuccess()` method is called when all the supplied tasks get completed. What we get in `onSuccess()` is a list of `DocumentSnapshot` of each document. We can now go through this list and get the `DocumentReference`.

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

For continuing after completing your requests for the selected subset, you would need to keep track of how many queries you're making and how many have completed.

Create a member variable to track the queries and within your OnCompleteListener:

```
@Override
public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<DocumentSnapshot> task) {

    mCompleted++; // Update your member variable

    if(task.isSuccessful(){
        // Do something with your returned data
    }else{
        // The task failed
    }

    // Check if the last query has completed
    if(mCompleted == numOfQueries){
        mCompleted = 0; // Reset the completed queries if you might run this process again

        // All of your queries have returned and you can now do something with the complete data set
    }
}
```

Comment: I appreciate the input, but this is an unoptimized approach imo. What happens when you have a lot of documents? It will certainly use too much resources on the client to iterate through all of them. In addition to that, It's not in my interest to write a whole collection to an array but only a limited amount (selected by the user).

Comment: @xblaz3kx Ok. It wasn't clear to me that you're requesting a subset of the collection determined by the user. You're welcome to find a better way to iterate through the results of a collection, however, the method I've provided you is the same as in the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/get-data?authuser=0).

Comment: When it comes to iterating through the subset, I don't think you have many options there. You'll most likely have to perform a request for each document, check each response to see if you've got all the data you need, and trigger the next process you want to complete once you've determined that all your responses have returned with all the data you need.

Comment: Exactly what I intended to do but got stuck since I'm new to async processing. This method doesn't exactly wait for the data to be sent to the client and proceeds no matter what I do. I have the same problem when calling an HTTP function when an update is successful, it just doesn't wait.

Comment: @xblaz3kx I've updated my answer now that I better understand the problem.

Comment: I think the solution might be Firestore Transactions? https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/transactions

Comment: @xblaz3kx Oh, yeah that would be much better. You would just loop through the transaction get requests, build the result from the snapshots, return the result after the loop, and retrieve the finished result in the callback. Yes, you're right. That's just what you're looking for.